# WPF MVVM - Set focus and Lost focus event calling repeatedly

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, textbox, focus

i'm new new to MVVM pattern, in my application when the validation for textbox goes wrong on lost focus of that textbox, focus has to stay on the same text itself, when i try to implement , methods for Set focus and Lost focus are calling repeatedly .

**set focus method**

```
Public Sub MainMenu_Focus(sender As Object, e As MainWindowEventArgs)
                      If TxtEditNDCClinicalScreen.IsEnabled Then
                ' TxtEditNDCClinicalScreen.Focus()
                Keyboard.Focus(TxtEditNDCClinicalScreen)
                If TxtEditNDCClinicalScreen.GetType() Is GetType(TextEdit) Then
                    CType(TxtEditNDCClinicalScreen, TextEdit).SelectAll()
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
```

**Lost focus method**

```
Private Sub TxtEditNDCClinicalScreen_LostFocus(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles TxtEditNDCClinicalScreen.LostFocus
            VM.CommandFind(TxtEditNDCClinicalScreen.Text.Length)
        End Sub
```

i also tried with interaction trigger, but no use.. facing same issue.

```
  <i:Interaction.Triggers> 
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus"> 
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CommandLostFocus}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text.Length,ElementName=TxtEditNDCClinicalScreen}"  />
                        </i:EventTrigger> IsHitTestVisible="True"
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

please suggest how to over come the problem
thanx.

Comment: Perhaps if you'd explain what you trying to achieve with this, then we'd be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: I have written the validation in textbox lost focus( ) event i.e.,TxtEditNDCClinicalScreen_LostFocus(), if validation fails ,focus has to be on same text box, so when i set TxtEditNDCClinicalScreen.focus, through MainMenu_Focus method by raiseevent from viewmodel, then the **loop doesn't end between MainMenu_Focus and TxtEditNDCClinicalScreen_LostFocus**

Comment: That is just not how validation is accomplished in WPF. Please read the [Enforcing Complex Business Data Rules with WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714593.aspx) page from MSDN for a better picture on how it *should* be done... no need for focus handlers at all!